# What would be a good Facebook credits price point for a puzzle game on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have a successful puzzle game and I'm thinking about doing a new version and bringing that new version to FB, and selling it using FB credits. Does anyone have ideas on what the FB credits price point should be? I have some idea, and obviously I know what some of the virtual goods price points are, but I'm curious what peoples views would be on a price point for an entire game, and if the availability of free facebook credits could hurt sells etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know of very few games that actually charge admission.  You most likely won't make any money that way, simply due to the fact that people can easily find something else to play with their time.

There are a few examples I remember seeing that lock certain modes behind a paywall, but if people are getting enough enjoyment out of the free one then they won't feel obligated to try the other one (this is the same problem with demos that give away too much).  It also isn't as good of a monetization strategy because it's something the user only buys once.

If you want to bring a puzzle game to facebook, my suggestion it to look and see what Popcap did with Bejeweled Blitz and Zuma Blitz.  They basically added a monetization layer on top of the existing games with things like purchasable powerups and the like.  They also made it very social with the weekly tournament idea and very visible friends scores.

Comment: My game has had a very large number of plays over the last few years, and people have been waiting for a sequel so I presume that there is definately an audience for the new version, who hopefully would be willing to pay a small fee, but I take your points and understand that it's not the usual way of doing things.

Comment: It's not the usual way of doing things because you'll get several orders of magnitude more users with a free to play game vs. a paid one, especially on a platform like facebook where people expect things to be free.